# Which configs/modules to disable or remove if I am using SailsJS (only) for a REST API with (only) MongoDB as the database. ? How to do that?

Tags: sails.js

I am using SailsJS for our production REST API. There are many components that we don't use in SalesJS. I want to disable those features, what is the best practice?

Some Details:

- We only use MongoDB (don't plan to change in any near future)
- We only want a REST API (only in JSON format)
- We DO NOT use any front-end, this just as a backend, don't plan to use any sorts or web rendering
- We don't plan to use WebSocket or socket.io

Which configs/modules we need to disable or remove? How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a ".sailsrc" file in the root project folder with the following:

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "frontend": false,
    "pubsub": false,
    "grunt": false
  }
}
```

Then I would check out the api/responses . There is no real need to alter these, but you could since you know you will have no view files.
http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses